# Wordpress Plugin for Authentication and Authorization?

Tags: authentication, wordpress

Is there a plug-in for WordPress that will allow me to be able to register users/visitors and to have them be able to only see certain pages and certain data ? My client has an insurance claims website that will have the insured and adjusters coming to the site. Both may need to register but certain data they enter into forms may need to be kept separated from each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you will need custom code, however the Membership plugin may be helpful to you: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/membership/ and the paid version has more options to limit access to content: http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership/

Comment: Thank you this is exactly the plug-in for the job.